# Can I still use my visa?

Tags: visas, usa, passport-renewals

My passport expires in May. I have a US visa, but my passport is in my maiden name. I'm planning on making a new passport with both my maiden and married last names. Will I be able to  use the visa? I need to know what to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The visa is still valid. In fact, once you get your new passport, the old one will be returned to you as it still bears a valid visa and you will have to travel with both passports.

The US State Department has a great [FAQ site](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/frequently-asked-questions/about-basics.html) which states the following:

> If your visa is still valid you can travel to the United States with
>   your two passports, as long as the visa is valid, not damaged, and is
>   the appropriate type of visa required for your principal purpose of
>   travel. (Example: tourist visa, when your principal purpose of travel
>   is tourism). Both passports (the valid and the expired one with the
>   visa) should be from the same country and type (Example: both
>   Uruguayan regular passports, both official passports, etc.). When you
>   arrive at the U.S. port-of-entry (POE, generally an airport or land
>   border) the Customs and Border Protection Immigration Officer will
>   check your visa in the old passport and if s/he decides to admit you
>   into the United States they will stamp your new passport with an
>   admission stamp along with the annotation "VIOPP" (visa in other
>   passport). Do not try to remove the visa from your old passport and
>   stick it into the new valid passport. If you do so, your visa will no
>   longer be valid.

For your name change, it is **recommended** to get a new visa with your new name, but your old visa remains valid.

> If your name has legally changed through marriage, divorce, or a court
>   ordered name change, you will need to obtain a new passport.  Once you
>   have a new passport, the Department of State recommends that you apply
>   for a new U.S. visa to make it easier for you to travel to and from
>   the United States.

You should travel with evidence of your name change (such as a court document - make sure it is in English) in case you are asked.

If you require to have your name changed on your visa, just go through the process of applying for a non-immigrant visa. Once you reach the interview, explain your circumstances. Make sure you bring evidence of your name change.